# Geometric interpretation for projection of a vector $x$ onto a subspace $U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

There is a theorem that states:

Let $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be an orthogonal basis for a subspace $U$ in an inner product space. 
The orthogonal projection of any vector $x$ onto $U$ is the point 
$\displaystyle p=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left \langle x,\hat{u}_i \right \rangle\hat{u}_i$.

Could someone assists me with the geometric interpretation?

Comment: I guess that $\hat{u}_i= \frac{u_i}{|u_i|}$.

Comment: That is correct. It's the normalized version of the 'original' vector

Comment: Write $\vec{x}$ as a sum of a vector in $U$ and a vector ortogonal to $U$.  The projection is merely the vector in $U$.

Answer (score 1):

A geometric interpretation is that if a subspace $U$ is the orthogonal direct sum of subspaces $U_1, \dots ,U_n$, then you can prove

1. That the projector on $U$ is the sum of the projectors on $U_1, \dots,U_n$.
2. That the projector on a vector line defined by a normalized vector $u$ is $q(x)=\langle x,u \rangle u$

Using those two facts (that are good to try to prove!), you'll get the desired result.